# MongoDb/Mongoskin - CLEANLY Update entire document w/o specifying properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

**All the examples I have seen for MongoDb & Mongoskin for update, have individual properties being updated, like so:**

```
    // this works when I specify the properties
    db.collection('User').update({_id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(user._id)}, 
     {'$set':{displayName:user.displayName}}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (result){ res.send(result)}
    });
```

**But what if I wanted the whole object/document to be updated instead:**

```
// this does not appear to work 
 db.collection('User').update({_id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(user._id)}, {'$set':user},
    function(err, result){
    // do something
 }
```

**It returns the error:**

```
// It appears Mongo does not like the _id as part of the update

    MongoError: After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('.....
```

**To overcome this issue, this is what I had to do to make things work:**

```
  function (req, res) {
    var userId = req.body.user._id
    var user = req.body.user;
    delete user._id;

    db.collection('User').update({_id: mongoskin.helper.toObjectID(userId)}, 
       {'$set':user}, function(err, result) {   
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('result: ' + result)
        if (result){ res.send(result)}
    });
})
```

**It there a more elegant way of updating the whole document, instead of hacking it with:**

```
   delete user._id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the whole object, you do not need a $set. I am not aware of mongoskin, but in shell you would do something like:

```
var userObj = {
   _id: <something>
   ...
};
db.user.update({_id: user._id}, user);
```

Which I think can be translated in your mongoskin in the following way.

```
db.collection('User').update({_id: user._id}, user, function(){...})
```

But here is the problem. **You can not update _id of the element in Mongo**. And this is what your error tells you. So you can remove the `_id` from your `user` object and have it separately. Search by this separate `_id` and update with a `user` object without `_id`.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what my hack job is doing?

Comment: @user1177440 sorry, somehow missed it. As for your question regarding a better way: no there is no way you can update _id of the object. So you should get rid of it before the update. A more elegant is not to have it there in the first place.